# I can not get auth_token when user login with google account at box's login authorization page

Tags: box-api

I was following the steps from box.net document 
http://developers.box.com/get-started/#authenticating

I can get a ticket as it said first.

Then I use that ticket at following url https://www.box.com/api/1.0/auth/{your ticket}

in a browser, it works as it says.  the browser will direct the user to box login page.

In that login page if I input username/password for login.

I can get the auth_token as the document says.

**The problem is** while I didn't choose username/password for login but use google openid to login an box account.

I will not able to get that auth_token as the document says. the returning response with following status:

not_logged_in

I want to know if this is a bug or I not correctly using the API to get that auth_token.

As many of box user now are using google openid as primely login choice this seems an common use case need be supported.

If anyone know the answer would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a non-OpenID user is able to authenticate through the Box API's standard authentication process, then your code is fine.  We have had reports of issues for our Single Signon issues, so this is likely a bug on our end.

Just make sure your app can authenticate users who have Box passwords.  When we resolve these SSO issues, OpenID users will be able to connect your app without any changes on your end.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy and looking forward to the fix.